# Проблема отправки писем. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня странная проблема происходит с классом CEvent::Send. Организовал рассылку писем адресам, которые берутся из `input`. `input` добавляются динамически по кнопке (нажал добавить email появился еще `input`). Все адреса собираются в один массив и добавляются `'EMAIL' => $values` Затем происходит отправка писем, письма приходят адресатам но их слишком много (я насчитал порядка 100) хотя кнопку "отправить email" нажал один раз. 
Код:

```js
function addUsesOutSystem() {
        var valInput = {};
        var i = 0;
        $('.edd').each(function() {
            valInput[i] = this.value;
            i++;
        })
        var data = {
            'action' : 'addUsesOutSystem',
            'valInput' : valInput,
            'IBLOCK_ID' : '<?=$_REQUEST["IBLOCK_ID"]?>',
            'ELEMENT_ID' : '<?=$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]?>'
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(json){
                console.log(data);
                $('.but').html(data);
                // alert(data);
                if (!json.error) {
                    $('.yes2').html('Отправлено');
                }else {
                    $('.yes2').html('Не отправлено');
                }
                return "";
            }
        });
    }
```

Код обработчик этой функции:

```js
if ($_POST['valInput']) {

                $values[] = $_POST['valInput'];
                $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_TO", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*");
                $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=> $_REQUEST["IBLOCK_ID"], '=ID' => $_REQUEST['ELEMENT_ID']);
                $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
                while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
                    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
                    $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
                    $arFields['PROP'] = $arProps;
                    $arNelikvid = $arFields;
                }

                $textItem = '';
                if (!$arNelikvid['PROP']['template_mail']['~VALUE']['TEXT']) {
                    $arPorText = array();

                    $arPorText['TEXT_POST'] = COption::GetOptionString('sinergo_post', 'TextPost6');
                    if (COption::GetOptionString('sinergo_post', 'ValPost6')) {
                        $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_POST");
                        $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_CODE" => 'POST_COMPANU', '=ID' => COption::GetOptionString('sinergo_post', 'ValPost6'));
                        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
                        $arResult = array();
                        while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
                            $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
                            $arPorText['POST_VALUE'] = $arFields['PROPERTY_POST_VALUE'].': '.$arFields['NAME'];
                        }
                    }


                $arSelect = array('SELECT' => array('UF_SHORTNAME', 'UF_DIRECTOR', 'UF_NAME', 'UF_MIDNAME', 'UF_SHORTNAME'));
                $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order = "asc"), $filter, $arSelect); // выбираем пользователей
                while($reg = $rsUsers->Fetch()){
                    $arUses[] = $reg;
                }

                $arPorText1 = array();
                foreach ($arNelikvid['PROP'] as $arNelikvidProp) {
                    if ($arNelikvidProp['CODE'] == 'ADMIN_PROC') {
                        if ($arNelikvidProp['VALUE']) {
                            $filter = Array(
                                "ID" => $arNelikvidProp['VALUE']
                            );

                        }else{
                            $filter = Array(
                                "ID" => '1'
                            );
                        }
                        $arSelect = array('SELECT' => array('UF_SURNAME', 'UF_NAME', 'UF_MIDNAME', 'UF_SHORTNAME', 'UF_MOBILE'));
                        $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="ID"), ($order = "asc"), $filter, $arSelect); // выбираем пользователей
                        while($reg = $rsUsers->Fetch()){
                            $adminProd = $reg;
                        }
                        $arPorText1['ADMIN_PROC_EMAIL'] = $adminProd['EMAIL'];
                        $arPorText1['ADMIN_PROC_PHONE'] = $adminProd['UF_MOBILE'];
                    }
                }

                foreach ($arPorText1 as $code => $val) {
                    $textItem = str_replace('#'.$code.'#', $val, $textItem);
                }

                foreach($arUses as $usesItem){
                    $textItem= str_replace('№В-0', '№ '.numMail().'В-0', $textItem);
                    $textItem = str_replace('#POST_ADDRES#', 'Директор', $textItem);
                    $textItem = str_replace('#COMPANU_ADDRES#', $usesItem['UF_SHORTNAME'], $textItem);
                    $textItem = str_replace('#FIO_ADDRES#', $usesItem['UF_SURNAME'].' '.$usesItem['UF_NAME'].' '.$usesItem['UF_MIDNAME'].' '.$usesItem['UF_DIRECTOR'], $textItem);
                    $arEventFields = array('TEXT' => $textItem, 'EMAIL' => $values, 'ELEMENT_ID' => $_REQUEST['ELEMENT_ID']);


                }
                CEvent::Send("Invitation_procedure_illiquid_assets", "s1", $arEventFields, "Y", 35);

                $json = array(
                    'error' => false
                );

            }else {
                $json = array(
                    'error' => true
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> письма приходят адресатам но их слишком много

Вот тут

```
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order = "asc"), $filter, $arSelect);
```

в качестве фильтра вы указываете `$filter`, который нигде не объявлен. В итоге вместо избранных вы получаете **ВСЕХ** пользователей.

Comment: Спасибо!!! $filter у меня в некоторых местах согласен не объявлен!!

Comment: Но вот почему письма одному адресату поступают раз по 100 чет не понятно((